# How to interpret merge information in TFS log output (or: how can I know which changesets is part of a build?)

Tags: testing

First the question, then some background.

We're using Visual Studio 2008, C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5, and TFS 2008 as our VCS.

If I execute this command against our TFS database, to show information about a merge commit:

```
tf changeset 13469 /noprompt
```

I get output like this (redacted):

```
Changeset: 13469
User: Lasse
Date: 12. november 2010 14:06:06

Comment:
  Some text here.

Items:
  merge, edit $/path/to/target/filename.txt
  ... more merged files

... some blurb about reviewer texts, etc. nothing important/useful here
```

This was merged from a different path in the same database, but this information is not available here.

For instance, if I merged from `$/path/to/main/` down to `$/path/to/branch/`, the path to the main project is not available in the merge changeset. *(note, please don't say that I'm merging the wrong way, it doesn't matter in this case so I just made it simple.)*

So, the question is this: Is there any way I can find out where that changeset was merged from? Which branch it came from? ... *and* which changeset it originated as in that branch (like 13468? 13462? 13453? ...)

---

**Background**

We haven't used much branching and merging so far, except for simple stuff like "tagging" a release.

From now on we're looking at using branching much more active, but this creates a challenge.

Let's say I open up our bug tracker, take the topmost bug, fixes it, and checks it in. This is done in one branch, let's say this is the master branch.

Now, at some point, a tester is going to verify that the hotfix we're going to release has this bug fixed, so he opens up our product and wants to verify before he starts that the bugfix has actually gone into this build.

When we didn't use branching, we simply took the changeset number of the commit that ultimately fixed a case and typed that into the case itself. Additionally, our product was built with a build-number (4th part of version number) identical to the changeset that was the latest changeset that became part of the build.

This way, the tester could simply look at the case, the version number and easily deduce if the build had that changeset or not. If the changeset number in the version number was equal to or higher than the one in the case, the changeset was part of that build.

With branches, that doesn't work. If I commit changeset X on the master branch, but forget to merge, the tester can't simply say "If I run version X or higher, I go that fix" any more.

Note that we're not using TFS work items, so there's no easy built-in way to link commits and cases.

The reason I asked about the TFS history output was that I assume that if I can see that changeset 13469 really came from another branch, and corresponds to changeset 13462 there, and the programmer has noted 13462 on the case, I can say "13462 is now part of the build, because it was merged to the right branch, became 13469, and the build output has version 13470."

In other words, I could build a tool that as part of the build looked at the history of the database and grabbed all the necessary information and stored it in a database, so that I could take cases on our ready-to-test list and compare against the version number of the executable the tester was running, and just list all cases that is both ready to test and part of that build.

So my question is really this: Does anyone have any hints to how we can solve this? Perhaps we're boneheaded and needs to be told the right way to do this, so if you got any good ideas, let me know.

Comment: The programmer that does the merge notes the merge changeset on the case as well. That was the best we could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I hear and feel your lament here, as we've run into the same limitation.  With TFS 2008, there's no easy way to see that history.  With TFS 2010, and the branch visualizer, it gets easier.

If this is something you really need, you could potentially write it yourself using the TFS API.  You would have to walk your way back through the various changesets for the files.  It would be relatively straightforward to code:

- Get merge changeset
- Get prior merge changeset
- Determine merge source from the first changeset
- Get history for the file between the dates of the two changesets.

I've done this manually before, but you could either do this in C# code, or, alternatively, write a PowerShell script to do this.